# How to detect death in Minecraft in a certain area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a PVP game and I need to detect when a player dies, but I also only want to detect that if the player is in the PVP arena. I want to be able to detect the last man standing and the one that died only inside the arena (part of the game mode). I have seen how to detect the death, but never how to limit it to a certain area/while they are in that game.

Comment: Can people go out of the area in other ways? Otherwise you just need to check if there is more than one person (with `/execute store … if entity` and then checking the scoreboard).

Answer (score 1):

**depending on the shape of your arena (square or circle),** you can restrict a command to run only `if entity` is within a certain range. i usually use, also, `execute as @a at @s`, as it quite literally targets (as) everyone (@a) as if (at) they were the individual (@s).

in the instance of a cuboid (square/rectangular area), you'd want to use the `x`, `y`, `z`, `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` arguments (or settings you need to specify) to choose the area you want to limit it to;

- `x` is the X coordinate of your first corner.
- `y` is the Y coordinate.
- `z` is the Z.
- `dx` is the distance on the X axis to the opposite corner.
- `dy` is the distance on Y.
- `dz` is the distance on Z.

so, for an example, if i want to make a player say "hi" while in a 5x5x5 cube area, assuming the center is  x0 y3 z0;

```
execute as @a at @s if entity @s[x=2,y=1,z=2,dx=-4,dy=4,dz=-4] run say hi
```

this would make it so if someone is in the area between the block at x2 y1 z2 and x-2 y5 z-2, it will run "say hi" as if that person ran the command itself.